# Item Rate based on Maximum Date

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables which is `Item Rate Table` and `Items Table` now I want to get items latest rate from `Item Rate Table` which is based on maximum date.
I use the following query but it works for `7-01-0001`, `7-01-0002`, `7-01-0003` item. How to fix this query.

```
SELECT
  `itemstable`.`SALE_CODE`,
  `itemstable`.`ITEM_NAME`,
  `itemratetable`.`ITEM_RATE`
FROM
  `itemstable` 
 INNER JOIN `itemratetable` 
   ON (
    `itemstable`.`SALE_CODE` = `itemratetable`.`ITEM_CODE`
   )
WHERE `itemratetable`.`RATE_DATE` = 
 (SELECT 
   MAX(RATE_DATE) 
FROM
  `itemratetable`) ;
```

### ITEM RATE TABLE

```
ITEM_CODE  RATE_DATE   ITEM_RATE  
---------  ----------  -----------
7-01-0001  2014-10-20  130
7-01-0002  2014-10-20  150
7-01-0002  2014-12-20  200
7-01-0003  2014-10-20  100
7-01-0003  2014-12-20  150
7-01-0004  2014-10-20  56
7-01-0004  2014-12-20  100
7-01-0005  2014-10-20  305
```

### ITEMS TABLE

```
SALE_CODE  ITEM_NAME
---------  ---------
7-01-0001  Item 1
7-01-0002  Item 2
7-01-0003  Item 3
7-01-0004  Item 4
7-01-0005  Item 5
```

### TARGET RECORDSET

```
SALE_CODE  ITEM_NAME    RATE_DATE   ITEM_RATE
---------  ---------    ----------- -----------
7-01-0001  Item 1       2014-10-20  130
7-01-0002  Item 2       2014-12-20  200
7-01-0003  Item 3       2014-12-20  150
7-01-0004  Item 4       2014-12-20  100
7-01-0005  Item 5       2014-10-20  305
```

Comment: This appears to be a standard GROUPWISE MAX query. But, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard GROUPWISE MAX query. The standard solution is as follows. I've omitted the other table for brevity. You should be able to figure it out...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM item_rate x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT item_code
            , MAX(rate_date) max_date 
         FROM item_rate 
        GROUP 
           BY item_code
     ) y 
    ON y.item_code = x.item_code 
   AND y.max_date = x.rate_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

The MAX function should be used at the top of the query, not in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT i.sale_code, i.item_name, MAX(r.rate_date), r.item_rate FROM
  itemstable i INNER JOIN itemratetable r ON i.sale_code = r.item_code
  GROUP BY i.sale_code, i.item_name, r.item_rate;
```

Comment: I doubt that this is what the OP is after.

Comment: Then I suggest you provide a better answer rather than commenting on this one.